# Sum current and prior year month-to-date to corresponding day of month

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

In the picture, I have a running monthly total at the bottom for THIS YEAR.  I have Last Year already populated.  How can I have LY monthly total only populate to where I am currently today?

[image: SO25556816 question example]

Comment: Sorry, the picture did not generate.  Basically I have in one column daily sales for This Year.  In column B I have daily sales for Last Year already populated for the entire month, split into weeks. At the bottom of the month I have a total.  Since the full month of this year has not been populated, my comp percentages are thrown off because last year has already been fully populated.  Basically, how can I comp TY to LY with only capturing sales up to the current day.

Comment: You need to post the pic or text illustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Generalising (for lack of a clear requirements statement - but conveniently then possibly of wider relevance) if you have two columns of numeric values with one (say A) of 31 entries and a column label (in Row1) and the other (say B) of 15 entries and column label and you want to add both down only as far as the shorter column is populated then you might:

In B32 enter `=SUM(B2:B31)` - to derive the "current month to date" total.
In A32 enter `=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MATCH(1E+100,B1:B31,1)))` - to derive the sum of the same rows (but different column) as above.